# Out of memory error while parsing simple JSON structure with large blob

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have to parse the following json response in android where `BookContent` is the content of book converted into base64 and returned as string. For some books, I am getting the very big string as response. If I cast the entire response as `JSONObject,(JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response))` it crashes, throwing *out of memory* exception. The json structure which I am getting is very simple but the string length of `BookContent` attribute is very big.

```
{"BookResult":{"BookContent":"3lWeX0Y1YaKdrOFr\/zD6W13fO67d\/zBow8f\/ERgtdbrn\/F6V1L79krYMeFHpp7D3FwOuYzDE5nI5iU0yh6UawZqmoam3sRATwI3DY9hIObHvoiB8Q0S+ver0KsO\/EoesVYErQs+SAEfF9JGXJV21+q16McesFbjpR2mPr3FMtMpGe2v+AIWK5hHu10iJ............","BookId":98,"Name":"Android principles"}}
```

Comment: Find a better way to distribute the book than as some large encoded string in the middle of the JSON.

Comment: Stream the contents separately, and write to disk. The JSON can have a link to content stream.

Comment: The response not only contains pdf, it also contains jpeg,png and other formats. As per our project requirement, all these data should be send only as blob because we have a iOS version for this same requirement which is working fine.

Comment: @ S.D. : Thanks for your reply. I can write the entire json response in file. But while parsing it, I should cast it to JSONObject as JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);obj.getString("BookContent") to get the actual content at where I am getting out of memory exception

Comment: @ njzk2: It is about 6 Mb

Answer (score 0):

```
Json Streaming
```

is the best option instead of bringing entire large json into memory
refer this link 
 
http://www.ngdata.com/parsing-a-large-json-file-efficiently-and-easily/